# Clojure string join escaped character

Tags: string, clojure

I'm trying to join a string for a shell command requiring pipe characters which need to be escaped. What I'm trying to get `"a\|b"` from `["a" "b"]`.

What I've tried:

```
(clojure.string/join "\\|" ["a" "b"]) ==> "a\\|b"
(clojure.string/join "\|" ["a" "b"]) ==> "a|b"
(clojure.string/join \| ["a" "b"]) ==> "a|b"
```

What do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first try was correct, you're just being tripped up by the escaping happening in the REPL display.  You can see more clearly what you're getting by using `println`:

```
user> (clojure.string/join "\\|" ["a" "b"])
"a\\|b"
user> (println (clojure.string/join "\\|" ["a" "b"]))
a\|b
```